# Make new variable by if condition in python

Tags: python

I have a list in python :

```
['ABCD_BAND1.TXT', 'ABCD_BAND2.TXT', 'ABCD_BAND3.TXT', 'ABCD_BAND4.TXT', 'ABCD_BAND5.TXT', 'ABCD_BAND6.TXT', 'ABCD_BAND7.TXT']
```

I want to pick `ABCD_BAND4.TXT` & `ABCD_BAND5.TXT` and define them as two new variables and do my analysis based on these two variables. I have written the following code but it does not works

## Assign Variables

```
dataList = ['ABCD_BAND1.TXT', 'ABCD_BAND2.TXT', 'ABCD_BAND3.TXT', 'ABCD_BAND4.TXT', 'ABCD_BAND5.TXT', 'ABCD_BAND6.TXT', 'ABCD_BAND7.TXT']
for item in dataList:
    if item.endswith("BAND4.TXT"):
        Item = "band4"
for item in dataList:
    if item.endswith("BAND5.TXT"):
        Item = "band5"
```

How can I fix it?

Cheers

Comment: What seems to be the problem with this? `Item` is first set to "band4" in the first loop and then `Item` is set to "band5" in the second loop. Do you just need to use two different names, say `item1` and `item2`?

Comment: How do you know it doesn't work?

Answer (score 3):

You need to declare two separate variables for storing the returned output.

```
>>> s = ['ABCD_BAND1.TXT', 'ABCD_BAND2.TXT', 'ABCD_BAND3.TXT', 'ABCD_BAND4.TXT', 'ABCD_BAND5.TXT', 'ABCD_BAND6.TXT', 'ABCD_BAND7.TXT']

>>> item4 , item5 = "",""
>>> for i in s:
        if i.endswith("BAND4.TXT"):
            item4 = i
        elif i.endswith("BAND5.TXT"):
            item5 = i

>>> item4
'ABCD_BAND4.TXT'
>>> item5
'ABCD_BAND5.TXT'
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use result_list depend on your purpose.

```
raw_list = ['ABCD_BAND1.TXT', 'ABCD_BAND2.TXT', 'ABCD_BAND3.TXT','ABCD_BAND4.TXT', 'ABCD_BAND5.TXT', 'ABCD_BAND6.TXT', 'ABCD_BAND7.TXT']

chose_list =  ['ABCD_BAND4.TXT', 'ABCD_BAND5.TXT']

result_list = [item for item in raw_list if item in chose_list]
```

Answer (score 0):

this solution works for me

```
>>> DataList = ['ABCD_BAND1.TXT', 'ABCD_BAND2.TXT', 'ABCD_BAND3.TXT', 'ABCD_BAND4.TXT', 'ABCD_BAND5.TXT', 'ABCD_BAND6.TXT', 'ABCD_BAND7.TXT']

>>> band4 = [i for i in DataList if "BAND4.TXT" in i][0] # 0 index for first occurance in list
>>> band4 
'ABCD_BAND4.TXT'
>>> band5 = [i for i in DataList if "BAND5.TXT" in i][0] # 0 index for first occurance in list
>>> band5
'ABCD_BAND5.TXT'
```

Comment: Looping through the array twice is not exactly efficient.

Comment: I have just improved authors code to work, and there was no efficiency requirement.